# Async ran during digest phase

Tags: javascript, pagination, angularjs-scope, angular-promise, alasql

I'm running this code in an Angular service, immediately upon loading the page. The controller **$scope** is passed as an argument to the function this extract belong to. The function is a **$q** promise.

I am not able to figure out how can I let the controller know that `scope.req.rows` has been updated. If I add `scope.$apply()` right after it, I run into a running digest phase. If I use the $q `resolve` function, it returns and no more loop results are returned. `scope.$evalAsync()` and `$timeout` seem to have no effect (at least without setting a timeout > 0). Same goes for `scope.$watch`.

How can I let the controller know that values were updated?

```
for (var page = 0; page < nbPages; page++) {
(function (pageNum) {

    that.get(url, 
             where, 
             res.pageSize * page, 
             res.pageSize)

        .then(function Success(data) {
        $log.info('Result of page ' + pageNum + ' received');

        for (row in data) {
                scope.req.rows++;
        }

    }).catch(function chunkFail(err) {
        reject(err);
    });

})(page);
```

Answer (score 0):

I build simple demo and it`s works. Correct me if i wrong.

**Updated**:
i mocking http request and delay it form 1000ms to 30000ms. and i steel have't any scope problems.
http://jsbin.com/wasoxe/4/edit?js,output

Comment: Hm.. explain what? requestEmulate function return promise which will resolve in interval from 300ms to 1000ms (emulation of http request). Resolve returns random generated array with length between 1 to 50. And all works fine, hove no any errors with $digest loop.

Comment: Well, my array must be created empty, **outside** the loop, and then I must concatenate inside it. Your code is confusing me, because it features both a resolve and a return statement. I'm not sure what either does, as I'm used to resolve() functions. So far I have been unable to make it work in my own context.

Comment: Can you discribe whot behavier tou want to reach? You want to concat data from all requests?

Comment: Yes. Although I originally hoped I could stream each result through the pipe. But `resolve()` works like `return`, it breaks out from the loop. I wanted to keep receiving each result and processing it as it became available.

Comment: Fixed. I just had to add an `if` statement making the `resolve()` conditional on receiving the last page. Still, it would be nicer to have a pipe.

Comment: I update example and it steel works, can you share your code?